# Playlist de musica com Pause e play

Tags: html5, lista

Olá, preciso fazer uma playlist de musica com html5 em minhas pesquisas achei muitos playlist, mas, nenhum deles tem pause no próprio playlist. Por exemplo, eu achei esse link http://jonhall.info/examples/html5_audio_playlist_example.html, e vocês podem observar que pode ir passando as músicas mas não pode pausar a musica na própria playlist.
Como eu coloco um botão de play e pause em cada faixa de musica sendo que quando eu clico na próxima a anterior para de tocar?

Comment: Mas qual é a pergunta?

Comment: @renan já coloquei a pergunta

Comment: Acho que vai te ajudar: [http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/07/html5-music-player-updated/] ou [http://mediaelementjs.com/] ou [http://www.shoutmeloud.com/best-html5-audio-players.html]

Answer (score 2):

Bem tranquilo de fazer com JS. [Aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) tem a lista completa de atributos e métodos para elementos áudio e vídeo.

### HTML

```
<button type="button" id="play">Play</button>
```

### JS

```
var player = document.getElementById('player'); // tag audio
var button = document.getElementById('play'); // botão play/pause

function play() {
    player.play();
    button.textContent = "Pause";
}

function pause() {
    player.pause();
    button.textContent = "Play";
}

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (player.paused) {
        play();
    } else {
        pause();
    }
});
```

E nas funções que trocam a música, é só chamar `play()` e `pause()`. (Óbvio que esse é um exemplo simples, em JS puro, podendo ser adaptado ao seu projeto).

Comment: obrigado vou tentar